# Getting an Android device orientation using ddmlib.jar

Tags: android, screenshot

I'm developing a program that allow the user to display on his computer screen the current screen of his android phone (connected to the computer via USB), through the use of the ddmlib library. I need to know if the phone is in landscape or portrait mode.

Is there a way to check this value from a program running on the computer?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my function to get this but it is quite slow. For now I'm looking for faster solution.

```
private int getLandscape() {
        int result = 0;
        try {
            String[] commands = new String[] { "adb", "-s", actualSerial,
                    "shell", "dumpsys input | grep 'SurfaceOrientation'" };
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process pr;
            pr = rt.exec(commands);
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    pr.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            line = input.readLine();
            if (line != null) {
                String[] lines = line.split(":");
                result = Integer.parseInt(lines[1].trim());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

The slowest part is to read from BufferedReader.

Answer (score 0):

```
class AReceiver implements IShellOutputReceiver {
    int x;
    int y;
    @Override
    public void addOutput(byte[] arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
        String xS = new String(arg0);
        xS = xS.substring(26).trim();
        String[] screenRes = xS.split("x");
        x = Integer.parseInt(screenRes[0]);
        y = Integer.parseInt(screenRes[1]);
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCancelled() {
        return false;
    }       
}
AReceiver receiver = new AReceiver();
try {
    dev.executeShellCommand("dumpsys window | grep \"mOverscanScreen\"", receiver);
    res[0] = receiver.x;
    res[1] = receiver.y;
} catch (TimeoutException | AdbCommandRejectedException | ShellCommandUnresponsiveException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Ffaster solution using `executeShellCommand`. On my machine previous solution takes about `400ms` to get answer and this solution gets landscape in about `50ms`:) Good luck with your application!